# Solving an overdetermined non-linear system for 8 unknowns

Tags: python, matlab, nonlinear-functions, nonlinear-optimization

I am wondering what my best approach is in the following scenario. I have 8 unknowns, however a virtually unlimited number of non-linear equations which makes the system over-determined.

unknowns:

U
M
V
N
J
S
W
N

equations:

```
U*M + V * Catime1 – V*M – Mgtime1 = 0
J*M + W * Catime1 – W*M – Srtime1 = 0
U*N + V * Catime2 – V*N – Mgtime2 = 0
J*N + W * Catime2 – W*N – Srtime2 = 0
U*S + V * Catime3 – V*S - Mgtime3 = 0
J*S + W * Catime3 – W*S - Srtime3 = 0
U*T + V * Catime4 – W*S - Mgtime4 = 0
J*T + W * Catime4 – W*S - Srtime4 = 0
```

Here's what I need help with:

1) identify which Matlab (or even within python) function will solve this set of equations.

2) generate the input (equations) using python using a large Catime(i-1) and Srtime(i-1) data-set.

Comment: if the solution is not unique, are you looking for a formula of all possible solutions, or do you just want any one solution? Check out this summary page: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html

Comment: @Amro - overdetermined, so unlikely an exact solution exists period, never mind uniqueness.

Comment: of course, what @woodchips said :)

Comment: I see now Ill get a least squares fit to the data. I am unsure though, after I define Catime, Mgtime, and Srtime (which is my experimental data), how I define the equations...

Comment: There is no such thing as an unlimited number of constraints (virtually or otherwise) on a system. I believe that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Write the problem as a Non Linear Least Squares problem and try to minimize it.

This will handle correctly the additional data you have.